# Sorting object's run states

Tags: enterprise-architect

On object's diagram, I have two different objects inherited from the same class. Unfortunately displayed run states are sorted in a different way. I am trying to sort it but the order of displayed values doesn't change.

Is there any way to sort it? I've tried to set 'Sort Features Alphabetically' but nothing happened.

Comment: Could it be that they are sorted in the order they are created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort that "manually". `t_object.runstate` holds

```
@VAR;Variable=<name>;Value=<val>;Note=<note>;Op=<op>;@ENDVAR
```

and it will appear in the order right there. So just disassemble the string, re-order as needed and replace it.

EAUI: The sort triangle in the Run State editor has only effect in the editor itself. It does not re-sort the real list. Report a bug (also about a missing "green arrow" which IIRC can be emulated by a strange key shortcut).